# Can I override a method in a JSPM package?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, systemjs, jspm

I'm migrating a project to use JSPM & SystemJS. In my app, I override a Backbone Marionette render method to use Mustache templates:

```
Marionette.Renderer.render = function (template, data) {
     return Mustache.render(template, { Model: data }, partials);
}
```

This was simple in the old world - just have the above code after marionette js and mustache js have been added to the page. I can't see how to override this when I'm loading it as a module though.

```
import * as Marionette from "backbone.marionette";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is just the loading order you can, for instance, create a new (i.e. custom) marionette module that depends both on **backbone.marionette** and **mustache** and extends marionette. Something like

```
import Marionette from 'backbone.marionette';
import Mustache from 'moustache';

Marionette.Renderer.render = function (template, data) {
 return Mustache.render(template, { Model: data }, partials);
}

export default Marionette;
```

After that, you'll need map your custom module on SystemJS config:

```
System.config({
   'map': {
      'custom-marionette': 'path/to/source/custom-marionette',
   ...
   }
}
```

Then you'll be able to import your custom module inside your application:

```
import Marionette from 'custom-marionette';
```